# Creating a Pandas Dataframe with Multi Column Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a problem creating a Pandas Dataframe with multi indexing issue. In the data below, you will see that its the data for 2 banks, and each bank has 2 assets and each asset has 3 features. 
My data is similarly structured and I want to create a dataframe out of this.

```
Data = [[[2,4,5],[3,4,5]],[[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]]

Banks = ['Bank1', 'Bank2']

Assets = ['Asset1', 'Asset2']

Asset_feature = ['private','public','classified']
```

I have tried various ways to do this but I've always failed to create an accurate dataframe. The result should look something like this:

```
      Asset1                      Asset2
      private public classified   private public classified
Bank1   2       4       5           3       4       5
Bank2   6       7       8           9       10      11
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on Python3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
assets = ['Asset1', 'Asset2']
Asset_feature = ['private','public','classified']
Banks = ['Bank1', 'Bank2']
Data = [[[2,4,5],[3,4,5]],[[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]]
Data = np.array(Data).reshape(len(Banks),len(Asset_feature) * len(assets))


midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([assets, Asset_feature])
test = pd.DataFrame(Data, index=Banks, columns=midx)
test
```

which gives this output

```
       Asset1                    Asset2                  
      private public classified private public classified
Bank1       2      4          5       3      4          5
Bank2       6      7          8       9     10         11
```

Comment: It has to be a n-banks solution. So the reshape wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Matthew. The very first solution that you posted works like a charm. I forgot to mention that the solution also needs to be a n-Asset_feature and n-assets solution. Your first solution was perfect. But now I'm getting the issue to convert this dataframe into a dictionary so that I can send it to my local host in a JSON format.

Comment: @SyedAhmed the multiindex should work no matter what size the assets and asset features as long as the data arrives in the shape you posted in your example

Comment: I changed some code that you wrote above and it works similarly. Instead of: Data = np.array(Data).reshape(len(Banks),6). I wrote something like this: Data = np.array(Data).reshape(len(Banks),len(assets)*len(Asset_feature))

Comment: @SyedAhmed i changed the answer to reflect fitting any data size instead of just the one presented in the question