# Creating empty pandas dataframe with Multi-Index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, multi-index

I'm trying to create an empty pandas.Dataframe with a Multi-Index that I can later fill columnwise with my data. I've looked at other answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58565302/11728010) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24290495/11728010)), but they all work with data that does not fill in columnwise, or that is somehow connected in the different columns.

The information I want to be contained in the Multi-Index looks like this:

```
GCM_list = ['BCC-CSM2-MR', 'CAMS-CSM1-0', 'CESM2', 'CESM2-WACCM', 'CMCC-CM2-SR5', 'EC-Earth3', 'EC-Earth3-Veg', 'FGOALS-f3-L', 'GFDL-ESM4', 'INM-CM4-8', 'INM-CM5-0', 'MPI-ESM1-2-HR', 'MRI-ESM2-0', 'NorESM2-MM', 'TaiESM1']
SSP_list = ['SSP_126', 'SSP_245', 'SSP_370', 'SSP_585']
index_years = [2030, 2040, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080, 2090, 2100]
```

And I want it to look somewhat like this (for the three first items in `GCM_list`):

```
               BCC-CSM2-MR                               CAMS-CSM1-0                                CESM2
     SSP_126  SSP_245  SSP_370  SSP_585      SSP_126  SSP_245  SSP_370  SSP_585       SSP_126  SSP_245  SSP_370  SSP_585
2030    |        |
2040    |        |
2050    V        V
2060    1        2
2070
2080
2090
2100
```

The "arrows" in the first two columns should represent how and in what order I want to fill the Dataframe after the Index is created - if that's important for this question.

I've tried building the index like this, but I'm not sure what to make of the result. How should I proceed? Is there a way to build this empty dataframe so that I can fill it column after column?

```
arrays = [GCM_list, SSP_list]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('GCM', 'SSP'))
>>> index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'BCC-CSM2-MR', u'CAMS-CSM1-0', u'CESM2', u'CESM2-WACCM', u'CMCC-CM2-SR5', u'EC-Earth3', u'EC-Earth3-Veg', u'FGOALS-f3-L', u'GFDL-ESM4', u'INM-CM4-8', u'INM-CM5-0', u'MPI-ESM1-2-HR', u'MRI-ESM2-0', u'NorESM2-MM', u'TaiESM1'], [u'SSP_126', u'SSP_245', u'SSP_370', u'SSP_585']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]],
           names=[u'GCM', u'SSP'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
arrays = [GCM_list, SSP_list]
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrays, names=('GCM', 'SSP'))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mux, index=index_years)
```